# Problem creating const object in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, object, constants

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile my code on Angular 7.2.0 with TypeScript version 3.2.2:

> error TS1005: ',' expected.**…

It is linked to the line where I try to declare a `const` object.

```
addAppareil(name: string status: string) {
    const appareilObject = {
      id: 0,
      name: '',
      status: ''
    };
  }
```

I don't get why it isn't correct, I've tried a lot of ways to do this but nothing worked good and nothing on the web that matches my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to put comma in arguments:

```
addAppareil(name: string, status: string) { // <---- In This Line

 }
```

Comment: Me too in the beginning :) Not a usual place to expect such typo

Comment: LOL i feel idiot now U_u thank's to you for such good eyes haha

Comment: Don't feel that way. Glad to help :)